# Dropwizard doesn't report metrics to ganglia

Tags: dropwizard, metrics, ganglia

I am trying to monitor my dropwizard web service using ganglia. I ran gmond and gmetad on my local machine. And I was able to see basic metrics(eg.cpu,memory usage) on ganglia-web.

I also added ganglia reporter in my service according to [this](https://dropwizard.github.io/metrics/3.1.0/manual/ganglia/#manual-ganglia). But nothing shows up on my ganglia-web.

```
private static final MetricRegistry metrics = new MetricRegistry();
private final Timer ingest = metrics.timer("MyApp");


    try {
        final GMetric ganglia = new GMetric("localhost", 8649, GMetric.UDPAddressingMode.MULTICAST, 1);
        final GangliaReporter gangliaReporter = GangliaReporter.forRegistry(metrics)
                .convertRatesTo(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .convertDurationsTo(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build(ganglia);
        gangliaReporter.start(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Can not initiate GangliaReporter",e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you entered a normal network address but tell GMetric to expect a multicast address. Here is what I used (and works):

```
GMetric ganglia = new GMetric("192.168.0.40", 8649, UDPAddressingMode.UNICAST, 1);
```

If this does not help you, please show your gmond.conf (udp channel config)